# How to find the pre-last(penultimate) value in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table

```
/*CREATE TABLE Purchases (
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    transaction_id INTEGE , 
    user_id INTEGER,
    purchase_date  datetime,
    product_type VARCHAR(30),
    price INTEGER   ,
    );
*/
```

And I need to find the prelast purchase of unique users. have no clue how to to this. Better if would be MYSQL.
I'm trying to serch for the last. But even that seems bad

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    
    LAST_VALUE(transaction_id) OVER (
        ORDER BY purchase_date
        RANGE BETWEEN
            UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND
            UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    ) last_purchase
FROM
    purchases;
```

Please help me with the seraching prelast purcase(stransaction_id) of the unique visitor(user_id)

Comment: mysql and postrgesql are two different database products. Removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually use. Also, if you ask if something could be done in one programming language, pls do not tag the question with a random other programming language without explaining the context.

Comment: Please explain what "prelast" means in this context.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: This isn't your table :-(

Answer (score 2):

If "pre-last" means the second-to-last (i.e. *penultimate*) then use `row_number()`:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by purchase_date desc) as seqnum
      from purchases p
     ) p
where seqnum = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Number the rows per user by date descending. Keep all rows numbered #2.

```
select *
from
(
  select p.*, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by purchase_date desc) as rn
  from purchases p
) numbered
where rn = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Invert the order, then use `limit` and `offset` to select the second row.